# Create strip around floor area

Tags: faces

I have a floor tile which is basically a square, but isn't quite.  I want to add a small strip around the side to be able to paint/texture this strip separately from the floor.

I've used some maths and the location of the other vertices to calculate the width of the strip.  I've then manually added extra vertices to the edge of the square floor, and manually connected them to "next edge" and run them straight along the x/y axis until the intersect with the opposite edge, to form a straight line.

Problem: doesn't create a face; without a face, can't select in Texture Painting.

So I took the 4 vertices I'd created and hit F to form a new Face.

Problem: have new face (one edge of the outer strip of my square) directly overlapping the square that was there before.

I'm guessing they haven't auto merged some how?

How do I tidy this up while ensuring I maintain my outer strip?

I have checked for doubles etc.

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 1):

The face created is exactly the one  you asked for.. you need to miter the frame to make individual faces around the rim. Delete the big face. You can use <kbd>F</kbd> with vertices selected to create the diagonal edges, and then <kbd>F</kbd> again with edges selected, to fill the segments.

[image]

But it may be easier to start with the whole tile, and <kbd>I</kbd> inset it with Offset Even checked, working from the outside in.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Easy when someone gives you the answer ;)

Comment: @Altissimus If an answer helped you don't post thanks in the comments, upvote it instead; and if it completely solved your problem, consider upvoting it.

Comment: I did upvote it, but I don’t have enough rep for it to count, so I did the old-fashioned thing of saying thank you.

Comment: you can also accept the answer, by hitting the check mark under the upvote option.  It let's people know that that person's answer fixed their problem